# Cannot set app to iPhone only

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have the following settings on my app. It should be iPhone only.

[image]

Like you can see I also get the iPad simulaters and my App is rejected becaused it crashed on iPad.

Does anybody know what is going wrong? Do I miss a setting ?

Thanks in advance !!

**EDIT**

Here is what the crash report says what apple send to me.

```
{"bundleID":"com.appmax.AFF","app_name":"AFF","bug_type":"109","name":"AFF","os_version":"iPhone OS 7.1.2 (11D257)","version":"1.2 (1.2)"}
Incident Identifier: 8C8A7A5E-85DC-4936-AB99-4A8AC19BCBCE
CrashReporter Key:   c770a653986db73b9d1205c822ac50e382e38abc
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             AFF [5920]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/E515D4D0-DC66-4726-A01E-BF2BB82969C4/AFF.app/AFF
Identifier:          com.appmax.AFF
Version:             1.2 (1.2)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-07-21 13:02:48.953 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x18bdeb100 0x1987c81fc 0x18bdefdb4 0x18bdedae0 0x18bd0d78c 0x1000e9484 0x1001b4b80 0x198da0014 0x198d9ffd4 0x198da31dc 0x18bdaaddc 0x18bda911c 0x18bce9dd0 0x191989c0c 0x18ee1afc4 0x1000ddb84 0x198dbbaa0)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198eb658c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000198e4a804 abort + 108
2   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000198070990 abort_message + 84
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019808dc28 default_terminate_handler() + 296
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001987c84d0 _objc_terminate() + 124
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019808b164 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019808aa7c __cxa_throw + 132
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001987c8314 objc_exception_throw + 340
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bdefdb0 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 216
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bdedadc ___forwarding___ + 908
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bd0d788 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 88
11  AFF                             0x00000001000e9480 0x1000d8000 + 70784
12  AFF                             0x00000001001b4b7c 0x1000d8000 + 904060
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198da0010 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198d9ffd0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198da31d8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 332
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bdaadd8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bda9118 __CFRunLoopRun + 1448
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bce9dcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
19  GraphicsServices                0x0000000191989c08 GSEventRunModal + 164
20  UIKit                           0x000000018ee1afc0 UIApplicationMain + 1152
21  AFF                             0x00000001000ddb80 0x1000d8000 + 23424
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000198dbba9c start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e9daa8 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000198da1998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198eb6e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198f35548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198eb6e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198f35548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198eb6e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198f35548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  AFNetworking
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e9dca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bdaad20 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bda8eb0 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bce9dcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   Foundation                      0x000000018c8852c0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 292
5   Foundation                      0x000000018c8e2d74 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 92
6   AFF                             0x000000010016717c 0x1000d8000 + 586108
7   Foundation                      0x000000018c96c408 __NSThread__main__ + 996
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198f37e18 _pthread_body + 164
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198f37d70 _pthread_start + 136
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198f35550 thread_start + 0

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198e9dca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bdaad20 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bda8eb0 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018bce9dcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   Foundation                      0x000000018c8de424 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 344
5   Foundation                      0x000000018c96c408 __NSThread__main__ + 996
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198f37e18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198f37d70 _pthread_start + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198f35550 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198eb6e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198f35548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198eb6e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198f35548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198eb6e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198f35548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000198eb676c __select + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198f37e18 _pthread_body + 164
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198f37d70 _pthread_start + 136
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198f35550 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000016fd254e8
    x4: 0x0000000000002060   x5: 0x000000016fd255a0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000640
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000009bd036f7  x11: 0x0000000000000300
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000198e63dcb
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00005e3808e74d3d  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000019bd162a0  x21: 0x0000000170135778  x22: 0x00000001701357a0  x23: 0x00000001700557e0
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x000000018f4a91ea  x26: 0x000000010021d7b0  x27: 0x000000016fd26cf8
   x28: 0x0000000000003603  fp: 0x000000016fd25520   lr: 0x0000000198f3916c
    sp: 0x000000016fd25500   pc: 0x0000000198eb658c cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: Is your app a Universal app? If no, then it won't run on iPad.

Comment: iPads can run iPhone-only apps... just not very well.

Comment: @trojanfoe is right. Any iPhone app can run on iPads. It just runs on a iPone sized screen on the iPad. There is nothing wrong here.

Comment: can you post the reason of the rejection, please? you might have misinterpreted something...

Comment: Run it in iPad simulator and see if it crashes ?

Comment: Some features may not be available on iPad (for example, apps that let you make phone calls or use the iPhone camera to take pictures).

Comment: Without a stacktrace we can only guess...

Comment: But how can I say that it should only run on iPhone and not on an iPad? Even with the 2x function ?

Comment: @trojanfoe I've edited my question with the stacktrace. Could you please take a look at it ?

Answer (score 5):

Any iPhone App , will run on iPad even if you restrict to iPhone in your Project Settings,Your App will be shown with a Scaled view for iPad such as Zoomed in version. If your App got crashed on iPad, then you would have to handle it, try to figure out using the reasons given in Resolution Centre or by running your app on iPad Simulator.

Comment: But how can I say that it should only run on iPhone and not on an iPad? Even with the 2x function ?

Comment: You may have to handle it in your app in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions seta condition for ipad using UserInterfaceIdiom such as if its ipad then just show an alert that "Sorry, this app is iPhone only" and show a blank background....to the user